# Why do `video` elements not fire `dragstart` events in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to make a `video` element draggable. The code below works fine in Chrome, but `dragstart` event is not firing in Firefox.

Is there any way to make it work on Firefox?

My OS is Fedora 29.

```js
  function drag(event){
   //event.dataTransfer.setData("text","test-data")
    console.log("drag firing")
  }
```

```html
<video width="400" controls draggable="true" ondragstart="drag()">
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: If you hide the video controls -- by not having the `control` attribute on the `video` element -- video becomes draggable. Firefox is misbehaving, obviously -- it's a quirk -- one shouldn't have to choose between a draggable and controllable video. But I can't seem to find any other obvious solution or error in your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [section 4.8.12.13 of the HTML standard specification by WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#attr-media-controls), the behavior observed by you is to be expected as it is apparently compliant with the specification, quoting a paragraph from the section:

> If the user agent [exposes a user interface to the user](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#expose-a-user-interface-to-the-user) by displaying controls over the [media element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#media-element), then the user agent should suppress any user interaction events while the user agent is interacting with this interface. (For example, if the user clicks on a video's playback control, [*mousedown*](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-mousedown) events and so forth would not simultaneously be fired at elements on the page.)

Answer (score 1):

`<video>` tag with `controls` cannot be drag and drop on firefox (06-2019), you can try to remove this attribute to make it work. Or you need some work around. For example, you add a wrapper element outside the video and make that wrapper draggable

Comment: By "cannot be drag and drop" do you mean that you have tested it on the browser you're using (which one?) and it does indeed not allow drag-and-drop, or that a standard specifies that a video with shown controls shall not allow drag-and-drop?

Comment: Ok, so it's empirical evidence. Also, what makes you think a wrapper will solve the problem? As far as I have tested, wrapping a video element that has controls, and attaching a `dragstart` event listener to the wrapper does not allow firing of the event either.